Determine if $\mathbb Q (\root4 \of 5i,\sqrt3)$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb Q$.
I've shown that $\mathbb Q (\root4 \of 5i,\sqrt3)$ is of degree 8, and that the roots of $x^4-5$ are $\root4 \of 5i,-\root4 \of 5i,\root4 \of 5,-\root4 \of 5$. I'm having trouble checking whether $\root4 \of 5 \in \mathbb Q (\root4 \of 5i,\sqrt3)$ or not. My guess is that the extension is not normal and I'm struggling with verifying that.
I could try finding what the elements of $\mathbb Q (\root4 \of 5i,\sqrt3)$ look like and then try to see if I reach a contradiction by assuming that $\root4 \of 5 \in \mathbb Q (\root4 \of 5i,\sqrt3)$. If indeed $\root4 \of 5 \in \mathbb Q (\root4 \of 5i,\sqrt3)$ then $i \in \mathbb Q (\root4 \of 5i,\sqrt3)$ also, so maybe it'll be easier to check if $i$ is a linear combination of elements of $\mathbb Q (\root4 \of 5i,\sqrt3)$.

Can you show that ${\bf Q}(\root4\of5,i,\sqrt3)$ has degree $16$? If so, that should settle the issue.

It is enough to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}, \sqrt[4]{5}i, \sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}, i, \sqrt{3})$ has degree $16$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Clearly we have the following extension degrees:
$$\mathbb{Q} \overset{4}{\subseteq} \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}, \sqrt{3}) \overset{2}{\subseteq} \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}, i, \sqrt{3}),$$
so it remains to show that $\sqrt{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5})$. Assume for contradiction that
$$a + b\sqrt[4]{5} = \sqrt{3}$$
for some $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. Squaring both sides and using the linear independence of $\{ 1, \sqrt[4]{5} \}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, we get
$$\begin{cases} a^2 + b^2 \sqrt{5} - 3 = 0, \\ 2ab = 0. \end{cases}$$
This gives either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, each leading to a quick contradiction.

We show that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5}i, \sqrt 3)\simeq\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5}, \sqrt 3)$, and since the latter is a subfield of $\mathbb R$ while the former is not, they embed into $\mathbb C$ with distinct images, therefore cannot be normal.
By Eisenstein, $x^4-5$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, $$\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5})\simeq\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5}i)\simeq\mathbb Q[x]/(x^4-5)$$
If $x^2-3$ has a solution in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5})$ (it can be shown this is not true, but we don't need to, according to the following argument), it must also has a solution in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5}i)$ through the above isomorphism, so $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5}i, \sqrt{3})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5}i)\simeq\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5})$.
If $x^2-3$ has no root in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5})$, we have
$$\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5}, \sqrt{3})\simeq\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5})[x]/(x^2-3)\simeq\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5}i)[x]/(x^2-3)\simeq\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5}i, \sqrt 3)$$
Therefore, either way, we must have $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5}, \sqrt 3)\simeq\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5}i, \sqrt 3)$.
The same method can be used to show the following stronger result:

Let $\alpha$ be a root of an irreducible $f\in \mathbb Q[x]$, such that $f$ has both real and imaginary roots, $\beta\in\mathbb R\cap\overline{\mathbb Q}$ such that $\mathbb Q(\beta)$ is normal over $\mathbb Q$ (or slightly weaker, the number field $\mathbb Q(\beta)$ is totally real), then $\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta)$ is not normal over $\mathbb Q$.


Nice argument! In other words, take $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q})$ such that $\varphi(\sqrt[4]{5}i) = \sqrt[4]{5}$. Then $$\varphi\big[ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}i, \sqrt{3}) \big] = \varphi\big[ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})(\sqrt[4]{5}i) \big] = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})(\sqrt[4]{5}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt[4]{5})$$ and the image is contained in $\mathbb{R}$ while the original field is not.

@Adayah Exactly. You have said it better than I. Here $\beta = \sqrt 3$ generates a normal extension is crucial, so we know $\varphi(\mathbb Q(\beta))=\mathbb Q(\beta)$, no matter which $\varphi$ is chosen. (Or if $\mathbb Q(\beta)$ is totally real, we don't care what its image is, as long as it's real.)

An element of $Q(\sqrt[4]5i,\sqrt 3)$ is like this:
$$a_0+a_1\sqrt[4]5i+a_2\sqrt 5+a_3\sqrt[5]{125}i+a_4\sqrt 3+a_5\sqrt[4]{45}i+a_6\sqrt{15}+a_7\sqrt[4]{1125}i$$
for some $a_0,\ldots,a_7\in\Bbb Q$.
If $\sqrt[4]5$ is a such element,
$$a_0+a_2\sqrt 5+a_4\sqrt 3+a_6\sqrt{15}=\sqrt[4]5$$
Squaring the equation,
$$(2a_0a_2+6a_4a_6-1)\sqrt 5+(2a_0a_4+10a_2a_6)\sqrt 3+(2a_0a_6+2a_2a_4)\sqrt{15}\in\Bbb Q$$
This yields the system
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2a_0a_2+6a_4a_6=1\\a_0a_4+5a_2a_6=0\\a_0a_6+a_2a_4=0\end{array}\right.$$
Then, multiply the second equation by $a_6$
$$a_0a_4a_6+5a_2a_6^2=0$$
Now use the third one,
$$-a_2a_4^2+5a_2a_6^2=0$$
So $a_2=0$, because $-a_4^2+5a_6^2$ cannot be $0$. Now,
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}6a_4a_6=1\\a_0a_4=0\\a_0a_6=0\end{array}\right.$$
Therefore, $a_0=0$ and $6a_4a_6=1$.
But if we multiply the second equation by $a_2$,
$$a_0a_2a_4+5a_2^2a_6=0$$
and again, use the third one,
$$-a_0^2a_6+5a_2^2a_6=0$$
we get that $a_6=0$, a contradiction.

Let $\mathbb{A}$ be the set of algebraic numbers, and $\sqrt[\mathrm{R}]{p}\subseteq\mathbb{A}$ be the set of all roots of the polinomial $p\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$. For $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}i,\sqrt{3})$ to be normal, we need to show that $E\cap\sqrt[\mathrm{R}]{p}≠∅\Rightarrow\sqrt[\mathrm{R}]{p}\subseteq E$ for every irreducible $p\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. We show this isn't the case by a counterexample:
Let $p(x)=x^4-5$, so that:
$$\sqrt[\mathrm{R}]{p}=\{\sqrt[4]{5},\sqrt[4]{5}i,-\sqrt[4]{5},-\sqrt[4]{5}i\}$$
$p$ is evidently irreducible. Obviously, $\sqrt[4]{5}i\in E$, so $E\cap\sqrt[\mathrm{R}]{p}≠∅$, however, $\sqrt[4]{5}\notin E$ so $\sqrt[\mathrm{R}]{p}\not\subseteq E$, as can be easily shown by the proposition:
$$\forall s,r,k\left(k\sqrt{3^r}\left(\sqrt[4]{5}i\right)^s≠\sqrt[4]{5}\right); \quad k\in\mathbb{Q}$$

Anyone cares to discuss their downvotes? Someone clearly didn't agree with my answer... If one can call "disliking" disagreeing.
